# Function to Merge Two DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to write a function to merge the data from two data frames countries and emissions for any given year.

```
  def mergeByYear(year):
    yearString = str(year)
    result = pd.merge(countries, emissions[yearString], on='Country Code')
    return
```

A user enter a year and the function merge the data frame according to the year. My data sample is :

```
Country Name    Country Code    Indicator Name  Indicator Code  1960    1961    1962    1963    1964    1965    
0   Aruba   ABW CO2 emissions (metric tons per capita)  EN.ATM.CO2E.PC  NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

But the above function give me an error "can not merge DataFrame with instance of type "

Can anyone tell me how to resolve this issue ??

Comment: the above data sample is for `countries` or `emissions` dataframe?

Comment: yes they are dataframes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without too much information regarding the data, here's what I could solve. I believe the issue is coming from using single brackets rather than double brackets for `emissions[yearString]`. Given some randomly generated DataFrames, here is what I could do:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
```

First, I created two DataFrames of random numbers, some would likely be strings in your instance but this is just a quick substitute.

```
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 100, 5).reshape(4,5), columns = ['Year',2,3,4,5])
```

Created one columns as a psudo-emissions column.

```
df2 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(0, 200, 10).reshape(4,5), columns = ['Emissions',7,8,9,10])
```

Added year data to the second DataFrame, which we can then use to merge with the first one

```
df2['Year'] = [0, 25, 50, 75] #Used to add year data to the second data Frame
```

I called the specific columns that I was looking to merge, including both the year and the psuedo-emissions column. I used double brackets here to call a list of column so the merge can still access 'Year' in both DataFrames.

```
pd.merge(df, df2[['Year', 'Emissions']], on = 'Year')
```

If the data frames are split differently than this, let me know and I will try to change it so it makes more sense to your solution.

Answer (score 0):

When you're merging, your `emissions` dataframe does not have the column `country code`.

Try

```
result=pd.merge(countries, emissions[["country code","yearString"]], on="country code").drop("country code", axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, maybe you dont need merge, you just need to add the year column:

```
def addYear(countries, emissions, year):
    yearString = str(year)
    countries[yearString] = countries['Country Code'].map(emissions.set_index('Country Code')[yearString])
    return countries
```

Another alternative if you want to preserve your countries dataframe:

```
def addYear(countries, emissions, year):
    yearString = str(year)
    result = countries.copy()
    result[yearString] = result['Country Code'].map(emissions.set_index('Country Code')[yearString])
    return result
```